# socket recv() returns weird value

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have a weird problem when writing a simple socket server and client in C.

The logic is very simple, the client sends 2 messages every time:

1. The data size (like a header indicating the data size it will send).
2. the data itself.

The server can successfully receive the first couple of messages, but after a while the data size message becomes some weird value.

This is the code and output.

**server.c**

```c
uint32_t toUInt32(uint8_t *buf) {
    return ((uint32_t) buf[0] << 24) | (buf[1] << 16) | (buf[2] << 8) | buf[3];
}

int recvall(int fd, uint8_t *data, int size) {
    int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
    int cur_size = 0;
    while(cur_size < size) {
        int size_to_recv = BUFF_SIZE;
        if (size - cur_size < BUFF_SIZE) {
            size_to_recv = size - cur_size;
        }
        char *temp = malloc(size_to_recv);
        int recv_size = recv(fd, temp, size_to_recv, 0);
        memcpy(data + cur_size, temp, size_to_recv);
        cur_size += size_to_recv;
        free(temp);
    }
    return cur_size;
}

while(1)
{
        uint8_t size_message[4];
        memset(size_message, 0 , 4);
        read_size = recv(client_sock , size_message, 4 , 0);
        if (read_size == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        printf("bytes are %d %d %d %d\n", size_message[0], size_message[1], size_message[2], size_message[3]);
        uint32_t size = toUInt32(size_message);
        printf("size is %d\n", size);
        uint8_t *data = malloc(size);
        read_size = recvall(client_sock , data , size);
        free(data);
}
```

**server output:**

```
bytes are 0 1 83 91
size is 86875
bytes are 0 1 130 117
size is 98933
bytes are 0 1 208 101
size is 118885
bytes are 0 2 141 253
size is 167421
bytes are 43 244 25 88
size is 737417560
```

**client.c**

```c
static inline void
buffer_write32be(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t value) {
    buf[0] = value >> 24;
    buf[1] = value >> 16;
    buf[2] = value >> 8;
    buf[3] = value;
}

while(1) {
    uint32_t size = (uint32_t)packet->size;
    uint8_t *buf = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    buffer_write32be(buf, size);
    if (send(sock , buf , sizeof(uint32_t) , 0 ) < 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (send(sock , packet->data , packet->size, 0 ) < 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    free(buf);
    sleep(1);
}
```

**client output:**

```
packet size is 86875, header size 4
packet size is 98933, header size 4
packet size is 118885, header size 4
packet size is 167421, header size 4
packet size is 167847, header size 4
packet size is 169004, header size 4
packet size is 169811, header size 4
```

You can see that the data size that the server receives suddenly becomes a weird large value, but the client sent out the right value.

What is going on here?

Comment: my guess: framing error?

Comment: `memcpy(data + cur_size, temp, size_to_recv);` is copying the number of bytes requested, not `recv_size` the number received.

Comment: `memcpy(data + cur_size, temp, size_to_recv);` should be `memcpy(data + cur_size, temp, recv_size);` and `cur_size += recv_size;` becuase there are no guarantees that `size_to_recv` and `recv_size` are the same value.

Comment: Also definitely want to look closer at  `recv_size` because it's also used to signal polite disconnect (with 0) and error conditions (with < 0).

Comment: `read_size = recv(client_sock , size_message, 4 , 0);` read_size could be < 4, here.

Comment: Aside: it would be more efficient to `char *temp = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);` before the loop and to `free` it afetrwards.

Comment: Thanks guys, changing size_to_recv to recv_size fixed the problem. So why is the `recv()` method returned before finishing all data read specified by `len`? Should I always use a while loop to wrap `recv()` to read the desired amount of data?

Comment: Just noticed there is a flag MSG_WAITALL to make sure to get the full data. Thanks again

Comment: Re "*why is the `recv()` method returned before finishing all data read specified by `len`?*", If any data is available, it returns it immediately. If there isn't, it waits for some to arrive. `len` is merely the max to wait for. (`read` works the same way.) It's far more useful that way. You can always call it in a loop until you get the correct amount.